# Strange csv.reader behaviour with excel-exported csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding

I've been trying to parse csvs saved from Excel and discovered by default these appear to be ISO-8859-2 (at least, chardet thinks so with an 80% certainty), and I can get them to parse that way.  But a single line gets read out as two separate lines in the parsed version.

I've set up my processing chain as per the csv module's documentation to open the source file with the right encoding, and run it through a [UTF8Recoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) to turn this into UTF-8 as it gets read in.

In outline it looks like this:

```
f = codecs.open("/path/to/csv", "r+b", encoding="ISO-8859-2")
reader = csv.reader(UTF8Recoder(f))
for row in reader: print row
```

For a CSV with a single line, this is outputting 2 rows!

Viewed via vim on the command line, the content of the csv is:

```
UCL,,,10.1016/j.neuropsychologia.xxxx,Elsevier,Neuropsychologia,DAT genotype modulates striatal processing and long-term mem<85>,091593/Z/10/Z,,,CC BY,
```

and the output is

```
['UCL', '', '', '10.1016/j.neuropsychologia.xxxx', 'Elsevier', 'Neuropsychologia', 'DAT genotype modulates striatal processing and long-term mem\xc2\x85']
['', '091593/Z/10/Z', '', '', 'CC BY', '']
```

If I drop all character encoding treatment, and let the libraries do whatever they want, I don't get this behaviour.  Instead it appears to work:

```
f = codecs.open("/path/to/csv", "r+b")
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader: print row
```

the output is:

```
['UCL', '', '', '10.1016/j.neuropsychologia.xxxx', 'Elsevier', 'Neuropsychologia', 'DAT genotype modulates striatal processing and long-term mem\x85', '091593/Z/10/Z', '', '', 'CC BY', '']
```

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?  (I notice \xc2\x85 has become \x85, if that is indicative of anything)

I'd rather be explicitly encoding the incoming data to UTF-8 so that I don't have to worry about it anywhere else in my application, and actually I suspect that not specifying the encoding during import will cause other issues, if my experience with character encoding is anything to go by!

Any tips much appreciated.

EDIT: this seems to be relevant: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2010_01_02.shtml

\x85 is a control code, which means "newline" when latin-1 is converted to unicode.

If so, I guess I'm going to need a way to stop that from happening.

EDIT2: this also is relevant: http://mg.pov.lt/blog/latin1-or-cp1252

It appears that cp1252 looks a lot like iso-8859-1 (aka latin-1).  I had considered this initially, but was referring to it as "windows-1252".  Initial investigations using input encoding "cp1252" look promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I've found the solution to this.  The final link in my EDIT2 above made me aware of a character encoding that I didn't know existed: "cp1252".  By an unfortunate coincidence a "normal" character in cp1252 is equivalent to the iso-8859-2 "newline" character.  So if you explicitly read a cp1252 encoded file as iso-8859-2 you will get newlines where you weren't expecting them, which is what was breaking the csv parser.

Note as well that despite apparent similarities windows-1252 and cp1252 are not the same, at least in that parsing the bytes may result in an exception in one and not in the other - I don't have any details on the exact differences between these encodings.

Note also that I made the iso-8859-2 determination of the character encoding initially based on running chardet over the data, which gave me that encoding with an 80% probability - which is not high enough :)

For the long-term solution to this in my software I've listed the common encoding formats that I expect from csvs, and I try them in order of likelihood until I get one that parses, AND outputs a csv of the shape I expect (in this case, exactly rectangular) - both parts are important because a file may parse with the wrong encoding but may not result in a structurally sound csv.

Comment: accepting my own answer.  Not just arrogant, but also the only answer available :)